# There is something wrong with my dog's stomach

Tags: dogs

Every once or twice a week my dog's stomach is rumbling every morning. she doesn't want to eat unless it's grass. and for a moment she will cram into me like she's in pain then suddenly cries. and after that, she will be ok again. help!

Comment: The sounds like symptoms that can only be addressed by a visit to your vet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a medical diagnosis, which we are not qualified to provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dogs will eat grass for a whole variety of reasons, but one of the reasons is for some form of gastric distress, which seems to be the case here. Clearly she feels that eating the grass is helping her and you seem to agree that there is some effect, but the underlying ***cause*** of that distress is something that we're not going to be able to diagnose for you, you need to get her into a veterinarian for an examination.

Just reading your question, though, here are some additional tips around observing your dog that I think is wise given the situation:

1. Check her stool, specifically to see if there may be traces of blood. I know it's a bit gross, but a lot of internal problems will show up in the stool. Your vet is very likely to want you to bring a sample in.
2. Observe her stomach area, does it appear bloated? A bloated stomach could be a sign of too much gas or other illness.
3. Is she in contact with other dogs? She could have picked up something up eating the faeces of another dog, you need to watch for that.
4. Have you more recently changed her diet? What is her diet?

Be prepared to answer those questions, I'm pretty certain that a vet is going to ask them.

Comment: thank you! And yes, we will visit a vet this week.